# ZeroBrane Studio for NodeMCU

Tags: zerobrane

I want to add all neccesary to use Zbstudio for NodeMCU development
Some time ago I've create the autocompletation ( https://github.com/hiperiondev/nodemcu-api-zerobrain ) and some initial menus for this.
Now I need to add in bottom tabs a serial terminal.
How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for serial terminal in the IDE at this time (as of v1.80). It may be possible to add it as a plugin, but you need to find a library that implements a serial terminal first.